# Надо запустить на Linux одно и тоже консольное приложение в нескольких экземплярах одновременно

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

Коротко:

Есть консольное приложение, я его запускаю и этой консолью пользоваться уже не возможно, пишутся строки, ну эт нормально. Цель запустить это же приложение в нескольких экземплярах, желательно по больше(+-50) одновременно. Потом хочу запихать это в питоновский скрипт.

Дополнение:

Если нет других вариантов буду рад совету как сделать это же с помощью нескольких пользователей, типо один пользователь-один экземпляр, хотя бы на примере с парой экземпляров, сам в линуксе не так силен.

Запустить даже один сеанс в фоне(с помощью "&") нормально не получилось, хз не выполняется просто висит, ну это наверно не важно. Возможно есть какие-нибудь приёмчики в "subprocess".

Использую ubuntu16.4, если это принципиально, могу другую виртуалку накатить.

Похожий вопрос здесь читал не оч помогло.

Comment: Ну откройте 50 консолей и запустите программу в каждой. Непонятно, в чём проблема

Comment: А если у вас "&" не работает, то опишите проблему подробнее (как воспроизвести проблему, скриншоты и т.п.)

Comment: можно ещё nohup добавить, а то мало чего там. Правда мы не знаем, что там за скрипт, может он не может работать в таком режиме (например, он блокирует файл на диске и вторую копию никак не запустить)

Comment: Я кстати не совсем правильно написал в предыдущем комментарии - надо вот так `for i in {1..50}; do <команда запуска> 1>/dev/null & done`  из старого комментария: по всей видимости процесс в фоне выполняется с & у автора, но stdout в терминал пишется, поэтому что бы не смущало, попробуйте перевести его в "никуда"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for idx in {0..50}; do  
python script.py 2> /dev/null > logs/$idx.log &
done
```

цикл на 50 запусков, каждый запуск скрипт логируется в логи по номеру